# Check CSS Animation (@keyframes) Support in Mobile Browser

Tags: css, css-animations

Looks like some old Mobile browsers won't support CSS animations and I'm using it in my website which is causing the texts on my site not to load.

The initial setting in animation is opacity:0 , But the space for text to appear is not even displayed,so I think maybe that's due to an incompatibility issue.I would like to redirect such users to another website I've created with no animations.

The code of my animations is

```
 .char{
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            animation: an 1s ease-out 1 both;
            display: inline-block;
        }
@keyframes an{
            from{
                opacity: 0;
                transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(-35px, -40px, -150px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 35deg);
            }
            to{
                opacity: 1;
                transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
```

Here's text Lies

```
<h1 id="h1" class="th">Here's some text</h1>
<h2 id="h2" class="th">These are some texts too...</div>
```

Here's the Javascript I'm using for animation

```
function myFunc(text) {
  var newDom = '';
        var animationDelay = 6;

        for(let i = 0; i < text.innerText.length; i++)
        {
            newDom += '<span class="char">' + (text.innerText[i] == ' ' ? ' ' : text.innerText[i])+ '</span>';
        }

        text.innerHTML = newDom;
        var length = text.children.length;

        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            text.children[i].style['animation-delay'] = animationDelay * i + 'ms';
        }
}

myFunc(text[0]); // call functions with your items.
myFunc(text[1]);
}
```

I've also tried some solutions by mozilla, but of no use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Detecting_CSS_animation_support

P.S For people who think this has solution @ CSS Animation Support

There's nothing really Helpful there

Comment: Use [@supports to target different browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports). Browsers who understand `@supports` also understand animations. You first write CSS that displays everything how you like for browsers that don't understand and then use `@supports` to add the animation for browsers that understand it.

Comment: @cloned Could you please elaborate it to an answer, I think this might work. But how do I integrate it with keyframes ?

Comment: Maybe ask your friend? :D

Comment: @cloned He told me it was to animate each letter separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @supprots [@supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports)

```css
h1,h2 {
  
  animation: an 5s infinite;
}

@supports (display: grid) {
    @keyframes an {
        from {
            opacity: 0;
            transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(-35px, -40px, -150px) rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 35deg);
        }
        to {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: perspective(500px) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="h1" class="th">Here's some text</h1>
<h2 id="h2" class="th">These are some texts too...</div>
```

Comment: Nope Bro, Still No Text appears :(

Comment: Slight change made in my question so that It will be more clear to you

Comment: @SimpleGuy_ because there is no text in the <div>, i am using box for example. Answer is [Edited], Now Check

Comment: I want it to be applied to h1 and h2 tags

Comment: Could you please look into the question again, I've added some more details in it

Comment: Now everything is okay, but what are you trying to achieve via JavaScript Code?